# What does the $foo: ("bar": baz, ...); syntax mean in SASS?

Tags: css, sass

Google Materialize defines their [color variables](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/master/sass/components/_color.scss) in this file like so:

```
$red: (
  "lighten-5":  #FFEBEE,
  "lighten-4":  #FFCDD2,
  "lighten-3":  #EF9A9A,
  "lighten-2":  #E57373,
  "lighten-1":  #EF5350,
  "base":       #F44336,
  "darken-1":   #E53935,
  "darken-2":   #D32F2F,
  "darken-3":   #C62828,
  "darken-4":   #B71C1C,
  "accent-1":    #FF8A80,
  "accent-2":    #FF5252,
  "accent-3":    #FF1744,
  "accent-4":    #D50000
);
```

I would like to use the colors with something like this:

```
.light-red-border {
    border: 1px solid $red-lighten-1;
}
```

How do I call those variables directly? They're used in other I can't find anything on this syntax mentioned anywhere.

**Edit:** I looked around a bit more in the Materialize Github and found some examples in [_variables.scss](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/f335fe6300fe799215c38585c30dced373e5dfc8/sass/components/_variables.scss):

```
$primary-color: color("materialize-red", "lighten-2") !default;
$primary-color-light: lighten($primary-color, 15%) !default;
$primary-color-dark: darken($primary-color, 15%) !default;
```

However, if you can direct me to an article discussing the syntax used to define the variables I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `map-get($red, 'lighten-5');` if you simply want the corresponding value from this map.

To expand on @weirdpanda's answer, these `SASS maps` need to be iterated upon, which then compiles into more CSS rules.

In the file you linked to, each of those colors is placed in a larger map of `$colors`:

```
$colors: (
  "materialize-red": $materialize-red,
  "red": $red,
  "pink": $pink,
  "purple": $purple
  //...
);
```

This colors map is then iterated upon, producing matching class selectors like `red.lighten-5` in the CSS.

```
@each $color_name, $color in $colors {
  @each $color_type, $color_value in $color {
    @if $color_type == "base" {
      .#{$color_name} {
        background-color: $color_value !important;
      }
      .#{$color_name}-text {
        color: $color_value !important;
      }
    }
    @else {
      .#{$color_name}.#{$color_type} {
        background-color: $color_value !important;
      }
      .#{$color_name}-text.text-#{$color_type} {
        color: $color_value !important;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To actually use these variables within SASS files (for instance, after importing `_color.scss`, you can access a map value with `map-get($map, $key)`. For instance:

```
.my-class{    
   color: map-get($red, 'lighten-5');
}
```

*Edit: regarding the `color` function:* The `$primary-color: color("materialize-red", "lighten-2")` line you posted is using a function defined in `_color.scss`, which ostensibly does the same thing as `map-get` but checks if the key exists in the map with `map-has-key` and raises a warning if it cannot be found.

```
@function color($color, $type) {
  @if map-has-key($colors, $color) {
    $curr_color: map-get($colors, $color);
    @if map-has-key($curr_color, $type) {
      @return map-get($curr_color, $type);
    }
  }
  @warn "Unknown `#{name}` in $colors.";
  @return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This syntax notation is called the `SASS Maps` notation and it is the SASS-equiv of a hash-map. Read more about it [here](https://viget.com/extend/sass-maps-are-awesome).